# Dynamic Button losing Bootstrap styling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I am adding my connect button using jQuery dynamically

```
// Add Connect Button

  function addbtn(){

//   alert("ss");

$('.messages:last-child').append('<li><div class="refesh-btn col-md-12 text-center"><button '+
'id="refresh" name="singlebutton" "class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Connect!</button> </div></li>');
```

This is the main html page where it gets inserted:

```
 <ul class="pages">
    <li class="chat page">
      <div class="chatArea">

        <ul class="messages">
        </ul>

      </div>
      <input class="inputMessage" placeholder="Type here..."/>
    </li>
    <li class="login page">
      <div class="form">
        <h3 class="title">What's your nickname?</h3>
        <input class="usernameInput" type="text" maxlength="14"  /><br/>
        <p id="cap" class="text-xs-center">Hit Enter to stay Anonymous!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But it is losing all its Bootstrap styling and acting like this [image]

Comment: `"class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"` -> `class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"`

Comment: Did you mean "but it is losing its bootstrap styling and displaying as a standard button as is shown here."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added extra `"` '*double inverted -comma*' just before `class` in the method.
Check out the [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/0gj2sLcq/) here.

**JS:**

```
function addbtn(){
        $('.messages:last-child').append('<li><div class="refesh-btn col-md-12 text-center"><button '+
'id="refresh" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Connect!</button></div></li>');
}
```